# Raspberry pi on remote network (all done works are mentioned in details)

Tags: ssh, cloud, raspberry-pi, server, remote-access

Firstly,here, I will mention all what I did to make raspberry pi as a web server or as a data cloud. But all the issues which were applied did not work. There are some problems in somewhere , but I dont know where, what , how.. ?

So let me start.
Firstly,I booted my raspberry pi with Raspian OS. It works in a best manner for sure.Then, I installed ntfs-3g to make it possible to read my hard drives by raspberry pi.
When I connected my hard drive (500 GB), raspberry pi went crazy,it freezed and so on.

I have two hypotheses. One of them , maybe hard drive could be so huge for raspberry pi to read and it could take lots of time to read. 
But someone could do with 1TB hard drive. So this one is dead!
Another hypothesis is that hard drive is formatted with NTFS. Maybe it could be problem. 
At first, I booted raspberry pi from a usb storage and when I connected that hard drive, raspberry tried to boot itself from hard drive, not from usb.That's why this is one another hypothesis. I havent disproved this yet. But i will and let you know.

Although I could not connect my hard drive to raspberry pi, I gave a break to that issue and I tried to create a connection from remote network to my raspberry pi.
I made raspberry's IP as a static. I could connect it from ssh and file zilla(ftp) LOCALLY. I disabled firewall of my router and observed my router's external IP. It has not changed for many days although I dont have a static external IP. Then, I arranged my port forwarding like these

"router_external_IP":8080 destination(raspberry's internal IP) is 22  (for SSH)
"router_external_IP":9000 destination(raspberry's internal IP) is 80  (for HTML)
"router_external_IP":8500 destination(raspberry's internal IP) is 3306(for mySql)

When SSH server and Mysql server ran on the raspberry pi, I tried to connect to raspberry pi

- by SSH with "router_external_IP":8080 (from putty)
- by browser with "router_external_IP":9000
- by browser with "router_external_IP":8500

NO ONE WORKED :( ! [By the way, I installed web servers on it, but i did not mention]

Someone can say that "Are you sure about ports are open ?". 
Yes I am sure I checked it out. But I am not sure on my router are forwarding these ports to raspberry pi or not . Also, I can not debug it.

Actually, I have 2 hypotheses on that also.

First one is that maybe router does not forward these ports to raspberry pi.
Second one is that maybe I am doing something wrong and that is why although router forwards all given ports to raspberry, raspberry can not respond.

I can not disprove these since I dont know how to debug.

I do not know what to do. I just got lost. Please help me on these issue.

Comment: 1. When you test the external ports, from which network have you tried? It might not work if you tried from the same network where the RPI is in.


2. Port 3306 is not HTTP you can't test with a browser, also it's not a good idea to open (via port forword) to public


3. What are the results of internal accessing the ports (22, 80, 3306) via internal network? You can use `telnet <rpi_ip> <port>` to test.

Comment: I tested external ports from internal network , in the same network with RPI. I will test from external network, maybe it could work, i will let you know.
I used 3306 since Mysql runs on 3306.
I can access RPI with 22,80,3306 from my internal network. There is no problem in accesing from local network.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check if your router is forwarding your ports is to check them at:  http://canyouseeme.org .  If, as you say, all your ports are open on your internal network, if "canyouseeme" can't see your services then you know you need to tweak your router settings.

Comment: I already did it and also mentioned above.

%%%%Someone can say that "Are you sure about ports are open ?". Yes I am sure I checked it out. But I am not sure on my router are forwarding these ports to raspberry pi or not . Also, I can not debug it.%%%

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding you.  I understand that everything works fine locally. & you have Raspbian installed.  So bring up your web browser on the Pi and point to http://canyouseeme.org.  Put in the port you're trying to check.  If "canyouseeme" turns green and says it can see your service, then you have correctly configured your router. If it doesn't, then you need to check your port forwarding settings again.  As for the filesystems on your drives.  I've never trusted ntfs on Linux.  I always format my external drives to FAT32. I have 1TB drive on my Pi. .5 T is not too big.

Comment: Thank you for your answer firstly. I am done with the port issues and also I dont know how I did it (Maybe I couldnt test it.) It worked suddenly and still has been working.

But I have still really big problem with my hard drive. I formatted it to FAT32 , it is empty right now. Tonight, I plugged it into R-PI and R-PI achieved to start itself and it came up for login. I couldnt write user name. I think it was really busy with reading hard drive although it is empty.
Did really huge delay occur in your hard drive to read it in the first plug ?

Comment: No.  I did not experience long delay times in reading the external drives the first time.  Log into the Pi with the external drive unplugged.    After booting into the desktop, plug in the external drive.  From the terminal, keep issuing the "dmesg" command to see how the Pi reacts to it.  If you're still having problems, post the last 10 lines or so of "dmesg".  Good luck.

Comment: When I plugged my hard drive to RPI , RPI did not let me do anything. 
it came to that
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9-OeUFDd5NyemN4cENJMnFjTWs&authuser=0

and it did not let me write username . 
Sometimes I read the outputs and it says like 
"kernel is not sufficient to read hard drive " and it counts someting in hex format and it comes to FFFF (as an address in the microprocessor I think).
Then it is dead !